# different ways of saying goodbye / farewell

Tags: conversation, greeting

In Korean I learned 2 ways of saying goodbye:

안녕히 계세요. When I'm leaving and other people are staying.

or

안녕히 가세요. When I'm staying and other people are leaving.

So what should I say when I'm leaving and the other people are leaving as well?

Besides that I'm wondering if there are other ways. Maybe less polite or other modern ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to say "안녕히 가세요" to the ones leaving a place as well.

The followings are different ways to say goodbye in Korean:

- 안녕 (informal). (Well-being, peace, health.)
- 안녕히 계세요. (Stay in peace.)
- 안녕히 가세요. (Go in peace.)
- 잘 있어 (informal). (Stay well.)
- 잘 가요 or 잘 가 (informal).  (Go well.)
- 나 먼저 가 (informal). (I will go first.)
- 다음에 봐 (informal). (see you next time.)
- 내일 봐 (informal). (see you tomorrow.)

Comment: and 내일 만나요 i suppose?

Comment: @yeouuu Yes it's like 내일 봐요.